# Hovering over parent keeps child hover effect, possible?

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling" data-modal=".child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When I hover over the `sibling` element, its border changes color and causes the `child` to show. I want to hold that styling whether sibling or child are hovered over.

I could add the css permanently to sibling using JS, then remove it on mouseleave but would prefer a css solution if possible

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sibling {
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  padding:6px;
  border:4px solid red;
}
.sibling:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  top:70px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

Is this possible?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve4zj3y2/2/)

Comment: Does .parent only ever have one .sibling and .child? Do you want only the .sibling hover style maintained? Sorry for asking after you accepted an answer (I deleted my answer, because I apparently misread), just interested to know how you will be using this.

Comment: Hey, yeah, only ever one sibling and one child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Add a hover condition to the parent.

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sibling {
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  padding:6px;
  border:4px solid red;
}
.parent:hover .sibling, /* here */
.sibling:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  top:70px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling" data-modal=".child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you want the parent class to be hovered on?!! the child class never appears in your snippet

Comment: It doesn't in his code either. That wasn't the question. The issue was keeping the border color change.

Answer (score 2):

i am not so sure if i get you right, but is this something you would need?

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.sibling {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.sibling:hover {
    border-color: blue;
}
.sibling:hover + .child {
    display: block;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    top:60px;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-modal="child">
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

pure css solution

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible

```js
$( ".parent" ).mouseenter(function() {
    var divName = $(this).data('modal');
    $(divName).fadeIn('fast').animate({
      'top': '30px'
    }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false}, function() { /*Animation complete*/ });
  });
```

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.parent:hover .sibling{border-color: #000;}
.sibling {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    top:60px;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-modal="child">
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check your snippet, it does not work at all. child div dont appear, border dont change color, nothing. I am assuming, you forgot to add the jquery library

Answer (score 1):

You dont need javascript, pure CSS solution exist. Refer CSS selectors and the "+" selector is what you need to control sibling classes.

So in your case,

```
.sibling:hover + .child{
    display:block;
}
```

controls the child class when the sibling class is hovered on.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
.sibling {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 60px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
.sibling:hover {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.sibling:hover + .child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-modal="child">
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps